# Removing elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri, how would I remove everything up to and including the body element of an HTML document? And also the closing body element and everything after?

Comment: If you are gutting a document, removing the entire body, it might make sense to create a new document and only copy over the `<head>` of the old one. Doing it that way is the other side of the same coin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (IMHO of course) would be to use XPath to extract the `<body>` element:

```
html = '<html><head><title>xxx</title></head><body><p>dsfkj</p><p><b>sdff</b> dsfsdf</p></body></html>'
doc  = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
body = doc.xpath('//body')
```

Now you have just the `<body>` element (and its children) in `body`. Then, to get the HTML:

```
body_html = body.to_s
# "<body>\n<p>dsfkj</p>\n<p><b>sdff</b> dsfsdf</p>\n</body>"
```

The trick is to extract what you want rather than trying to throw away what you don't want. The end result is the same but finding one thing that you want it easier than finding a bunch of things you don't want when you have a query language at your disposal.

Comment: This is so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it! Thanks!

Comment: @Michael: It is incredibly easy to get locked into the wrong approach and waste hours trying to force it work when a fresh set of eyes can sort out your problem in a couple minutes. Been there, done that, didn't even get a crappy t-shirt for it.

Comment: Rather than use `to_s` to get the HTML, use `to_html`. It's more self-documenting. Also, when working with HTML, I use the CSS accessors rather than XPath, and `at` which returns a node rather than `xpath` which returns a NodeSet, for explicit lookups of single tags, such as `<body>` or `<head>`, so `body = doc.at('body')` and `body_html = body.to_html`.